# Access the ActionBar from within a Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-support-library

How do you access the ActionBar from within a Fragment (android.support.v4.app.Fragment).  I am using the Android Support Library v4 and v7.  I'm not using the Sherlock library's.

The activity hosting the fragment is an ActionBarActivity.

I have read the Android help section [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html) which led me too getActivity() but there is no getSupportActionBar() method.

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getSupportActionBar()
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> I have read the Android help section Fragment which led me too getActivity() but there is no getSupportActionBar() method.

You will need to cast the result of `getActivity()` to be an `ActionBarActivity`, on which you will find `getSupportActionBar()`.

Comment: So simple when you know how.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: For those who could not get what he said, simply use this code
    
`ActionBar actionBar = ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();`

Comment: Or you can cast as AppCompatActivity.  Here is a kotlin example

(activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

Answer (score 9):

If you are using **AppCompatActivity** then do it like this.
       `((AppCompatActivity )getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();`

Also it is advised to shift to **Toolbar** with AppCompatActivity instead of action bar(app bar). For more details refer this http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html